# Check value of UserDefaults and create an IF statement

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm trying to allow the user to purchase a node using coins and then use this node in gameplay.

I've attempted to set up some code which checks whether the node has been touched/purchased before and if not, display a greyed out image of the node.

Also, if the users coin amount is greater than an integer, then touches enabled on the node allowing them to purchase it.

This is what I've thought I could use to see whether the node has been purchased/touched before and if not, give the ability to touch/purchase if they have sufficient coins:

```
    if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "ship2") == true{
        let ship2Texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ship2.png")
        ship2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: ship2Texture)
        ship2.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX - 150, y: self.frame.midY)
        self.addChild(ship2)
    }else{
        coinImage1 = SKSpriteNode(texture: coinImageTexture)
        coinImage1.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX - 150, y: self.frame.midY + 105)
        coinImage1.zPosition = 1
        self.addChild(coinImage1)

        coinLabel1.fontName = "MarkerFelt-Thin"
        coinLabel1.fontSize = 25
        coinLabel1.fontColor = .black
        coinLabel1.text = "20"
        coinLabel1.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX - 150, y: self.frame.midY + 105)
        coinLabel1.zPosition = 1.1
        self.addChild(coinLabel1)

        let greyship2Texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "greyship2.png")
        greyship2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: greyship2Texture)
        greyship2.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX - 150, y: self.frame.midY)

        self.addChild(greyship2)
    }
```

Now here is what I have in my touches Began:

```
 if(atPoint(location) == greyship2) {
       if coinScore > 3 {
            let oldValue = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "COINSCORE")
            let newValue = oldValue - 20
            UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "COINSCORE")
            UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "ship2")
        } else {

        }
  }
   if(atPoint(location) == ship2){
        if let scene = GameScene2(fileNamed: "GameScene2") {
             // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
             scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

             // Present the scene
             view!.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.doorway(withDuration: 1.2));    
            }
    }
```

The only problem is that when the user has sufficient coins and touches the greyship2 it doesn't then check the initial code. I have to re launch the app for the coinScore to reduce by 20 and for the coloured ship to actually appear.

I've tried putting the first section of code in the update function but it crashes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you are not updating the UI after it has been purchased. You are changing the UserDefaults value so next time it runs it will show the correct sprite. But what you need to do is update the UI after the purchase, as your code where your choosing the sprite depending on your UserDefaults value isn't being run again. If your first bit of code is in a function then you can just call the function after the purchase has been made.

Also it is a good idea to call `UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()` once you have changed the values so it gets written to disk immediately.

Try this

```
if(greyship2.contains(location)) {
    if coinScore > 3 {
        let oldValue = UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: "COINSCORE")
        let newValue = oldValue - 20

        UserDefaults.standard.set(newValue, forKey: "COINSCORE")
        UserDefaults.standard.set(true, forKey: "ship2")
        UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()

        //Now it has been brought update the UI and other necessary things

        //If the code is in a function call it

        //updateUI()

        //else change the sprites

        //Remove the grey ship
        greyship2.setScale(0)
        greyship2.removeFromParent()

        //create the new ship and add it to the scene
        let ship2Texture = SKTexture(imageNamed: "ship2.png")
        ship2 = SKSpriteNode(texture: ship2Texture)
        ship2.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX - 150, y: self.frame.midY)
        ship2.setScale(1)
        self.addChild(ship2)
        break //finish the touchesbegan call
     }
}

if(ship2.contains(location)) {
        if let scene = GameScene2(fileNamed: "GameScene2") {
             // Set the scale mode to scale to fit the window
             scene.scaleMode = .aspectFill

             // Present the scene
             view!.presentScene(scene, transition: SKTransition.doorway(withDuration: 1.2));    
        }
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: The only reason to call synchronize explicitly here is because the app might crash before it is saved automatically. If the app works, this isn't needed.

Comment: That's working great. The only problem is that when coinScore > 3 and I touch the greyShip. It also triggers the code for touching the ship2 also. So rather than the ship2 appearing and then tapping on the ship 2 to change scene it does the whole lot in one touch? Hope this makes sense

Comment: I think I understand trying setting the scale of the gray ship to 0 once it has been brought.

Comment: @rmaddy I though it was good idea to call synchronise but I'm mistaken.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by setting the scale of the grey ship? The problem is once touched it immediately transitions to game play instead of first displaying he coloured ship and then upon another tap transitions

Comment: I have updated my answer see if it works for you now?